# Firebase Query - Nested Data

Tags: firebase

I am attempting to query some hierarchical data in firebase. I'm having a little difficulty in figuring out how to query the following data structure:

```
{
  "orgs": {
    "-KBFXBBEyvgtfqMvU4pi": {
      "name": "ACME 123",
      "owner": "-K9IPqIUIuEFzLS0f_Pe",
      "users": {
        "-KBF_GhwTmXfR6Jce30t": {
          "email": "userA@company.com",
          "permission": "editor",
          "userKey": "K99LV9cTjh1ovW1D5j2"
        },
        "-KBF_M533zzbUilGvAAW": {
          "email": "userB@company.com",
          "permission": "editor"
        }
      }
    },
    "-KBFaKlJ8tfqjBQjAZgq": {
      "name": "ACME Alt LLC",
      "owner": "-K9IPqIUIuEFzLS0f_ZZ",
      "users": {
        "-KBFbD4trt9nyeHPUQbn": {
          "email": "userX@co.com",
          "permission": "editor"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Specifically, I would like to find out if the email address "userB@company.com" exists. But this is a little confusing for me since I need to search through 2 levels (orgs and users).

Answer (score 1):

After reading some more documentation it seems I really shouldn't be nesting my data like this. I'll be honest, it seems kind of contrary to do this when working with a JSON schema that that is hierarchical. Anyway, this is what I'm looking to do now:

```
{
  "orgs": {
    "-KBFXBBEyvgtfqMvU4pi": {
      "name": "ACME 123",
      "owner": "-K9IPqIUIuEFzLS0f_Pe"
      }
    },
    "-KBFaKlJ8tfqjBQjAZgq": {
      "name": "ACME Alt LLC",
      "owner": "-K9IPqIUIuEFzLS0f_ZZ"
      }
    }
  },
  "orgMembership": {
    "-KBFXBBEyvgtfq7h381h": {
      "org": "-KBFXBBEyvgtfqMvU4pi",
      "email": "userA@company.com",
      "permission": "editor"
  }
}
```

Then I can use the following query:

```
orgMRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo("userA@company.com").once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("found: " + snapshot.key());
});
```

Comment: Yup. Alternatively, add another node `memberOrgs` where you keep the opposite of `orgMemberships`: the orgs that a user is a member of. With that in place, you can look up the info with a query: `ref.child('memberOrgs').child(auth.uid).once('value'` The only thing faster than a well-index query is doing no query at all, but accessing the data directly.

Comment: Thanks. I was planning on doing something similar to that in that I was going to add a property called `org` to my `users` data. The good news here is that my business requirements are that a user can only belong to one org. When the user signs up I try to find them in `orgMembership` and then assign their `org` if they match. My next challenge will be coming up with security rules for this data. `orgMembership` is essentially an invite/share mechanism.