# Firebase equalTo not working on non-root nodes

Tags: android, firebase

## Here is my data structure

Root
|
 ---users
         |
         ----publicProfiles
                                    |
                                     ------ some self generated ID
                                       |
                                       ----phoneNumber:4441113444

## My code

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/users/publicProfile");
Query query = ref.orderByChild(User.TAG_phoneNumber)
                 .equalTo(mPhoneNum.getText().toString().trim());
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener())
```

The ValueEventListener dont return any data.
If I remove the equalTo then I get all the phone numbers back.

Also If I remove publicProfile sub-root and directly put the data under users then the logic works.

I have concluded that equalTo doesnt work on non-root nodes.

Comment: You'll have to rethink your data structure anyway, because with a data structure that deep, you're bound to encounter performance issues as you scale. I.e. you need to flatten your data structure in the interest of performance, even if it causes "redundancies".

Comment: Firebase cannot query such a nested structure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591023/firebase-query-nested-data